# The \colon symbol has disappeared

Tags: pdftex, symbols

I have just realized that the "\colon" is not visualized in my pdf after compiling. What do you think is going on? I am new of here, so if you need something like the code, let me know!

Thanks to everybody.

```
    \documentclass[twoside,11pt,b5paper]{book}
\usepackage[dvips=false,pdftex=false,vtex=false]{geometry}
\usepackage[a4,center]{crop}
\geometry{%
 includeheadfoot,
 margin=2cm
 }

\makeatletter               %niente numero alla prima pagina del nuovo capitolo
\renewcommand\chapter{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
                \thispagestyle{empty}%
                \global\@topnum\z@
                \@afterindentfalse
                \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
\makeatother

\title{\scshape{Geometria delle Grassmanniane e Teoremi di Torelli}}
\author{Unknown}

\usepackage{palatino,eulervm}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage[pagestyles, clearempty,explicit]{titlesec}
\newcommand*{\sectionfont}{\fontfamily{ppl}\selectfont}
\titleformat{\section}[display]{\bfseries \sectionfont}{}{0pt}{\thesection   \quad  #1}[]
\titlespacing*{\section}{-0.9cm}{2pt}{0.5cm}[-0pt]

\usepackage{fourier, erewhon, cabin}
\usepackage[protrusion=true, expansion]{microtype}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]{}{\eqmakebox[chap]{\large    \MakeUppercase{\sffamily\lsstyle\chaptername} %
\raisebox{-0.6\height}{\fontsize{50pt}{50pt}\selectfont\thechapter}\quad}}%
 {0pt}{\huge\bfseries\raisebox{1ex}{\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-    \eqboxwidth{chap}\relax}{\titlerule[2pt]\vspace{1.25ex}#1}}}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-32pt}{35pt}%


 \usepackage{fancyhdr}
 \pagestyle{fancy}
 \fancyhf{}
 \fancyhead[RE]{\small \leftmark}
 \fancyhead[LO]{\small \rightmark}
 \fancyfoot[RE,LO]{\small \thepage}
 \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
 \pagenumbering{arabic}
 \usepackage{tikz,tikz-cd}




\linespread{1} 

\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts,mathrsfs}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}
\usepackage[colorlinks = true,
        linkcolor = blue,
        urlcolor  = blue,
        citecolor = blue,
        anchorcolor = blue]{hyperref}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposizione}
\newtheorem{thm}{Teorema}
\newtheorem{cor}{Corollario}
\theoremstyle{definition}

\renewcommand{\square}{ \tikz[baseline=-.2ex] \filldraw   [fill=red!60!black, draw=black] (0,0) rectangle (1ex,1ex) ;} 
\newtheorem{example}{\square \;  Esempio}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{rmk}{Osservazione}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{notz}{Notazione}

\renewcommand\qedsymbol{$\blacksquare$}

\tcbuselibrary{theorems}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{propn}{Proposizione}{coltitle=black, detach title, before upper={\tcbtitle\quad}, colback=black!3!white,colframe=black!60!red,fonttitle=\bfseries, arc=0mm, separator sign dash, description delimiters={\grqq}{\grqq}, terminator sign colon}{propn} %questo serve per il ref

    \newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{defn}{Definizione}{leftrule=2mm,     coltitle=black, detach title, before upper={\tcbtitle\quad},      colback=black!3!white, colframe=black!60!red, fonttitle=\bfseries, arc=0mm,      separator sign dash, description delimiters={\grqq}{\grqq}, terminator sign     colon}{defn}

     \newtcbtheorem[number within=chapter]{examp}{\square \; Esempio}    {coltitle=black, detach title, before upper={\tcbtitle\quad}, colback=white,     colframe=white, fonttitle=\bfseries, arc=0mm, separator sign dash,terminator      sign colon}{examp}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\chapter{A chapter}
$f \colon A \to B$ is a function.
\section{A section}
Some text.
\end{document}
```

UPDATE: i realized that if a cancel this, then the colon is visualized, but i need this part.

```
    \usepackage{fourier, erewhon, cabin}
\usepackage[protrusion=true, expansion]{microtype}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]{}{\eqmakebox[chap]{\large    \MakeUppercase{\sffamily\lsstyle\chaptername} %
\raisebox{-0.6\height}{\fontsize{50pt}{50pt}\selectfont\thechapter}\quad}}%
{0pt}{\huge\bfseries\raisebox{1ex}{\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-\eqboxwidth{chap}\relax}{\titlerule[2pt]\vspace{1.25ex}#1}}}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-32pt}{35pt}%
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Yes, simbols disappearing is not normal, so the code would be a good start to find out what the problem is. Please make a compilable example of your document which (doesn't, in this case) produce the expected output.

Comment: Do you think that the preamble should suffice?

Comment: Welcome! We need code we can compile to reproduce the problem. If you're using LaTeX, it should begin `\documentclass{}` and end `\end{document}` and, when compiled, it should unexpectedly have no colons when `\colon` is used in maths mode. Are you sure you aren't getting errors?

Comment: Yes, no errors! I am posting a working code!

Comment: Of Course i am sorry if the code is not so good. I am writing my thesis and trying to get the best possible with minimum knowledge.

Comment: Either you remove `\usepackage{palatino,eulervm}` or `\usepackage{fourier,erewhon,cabin}`. If you want Utopia, keep the latter; if you want Palatino for text and Euler for math, keep the former.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your log shows

```
Missing character: There is no º in font futsy!
```

This lets you narrow down your example to a just focus on font packages, which finally leads to the `amsmath` definition of `\colon` being incompatible with one of teh font sets you are using. The simplest thing is to save the original definition.

```
    \documentclass[twoside,11pt,b5paper]{book}

\title{\scshape{Geometria delle Grassmanniane e Teoremi di Torelli}}
\author{Unknown}

\usepackage{palatino,eulervm}

\usepackage{fourier, erewhon, cabin}
\usepackage[protrusion=true, expansion]{microtype}






\linespread{1} 

\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts,mathrsfs}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\let\oldcolon=\colon
\usepackage{amsmath}% included by tcolorbox


\begin{document}

$f \colon A \to B$ is a function.

$f \oldcolon A \to B$ is a function.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Next you have to cure `\hbar`, `\hslash` and a few other symbols that don't print correctly.

Comment: @egreg only if I get a new question and 15pt for each one

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in having these two lines:

```latex
\usepackage{palatino,eulervm}

\usepackage{fourier,erewhon,cabin}
```

The first line sets up the document for Palatino (text) and Euler (math). The second line sets up the document for Utopia (text, with the erewhon clone) and Fourier (math, Utopia compatible). The `cabin` package chooses a sans serif font and is not involved in the problem.

There is no point in doing contradictory font choices; much less if you consider that `eulervm` and `fourier` uses non standard encoding for the math fonts, so both change the default math tables. You can try and see that both `\hbar` and `\hslash` would print a lowercase Greek kappa, for instance. So the missing colon is only a symptom and the cure is not acting just on it.

Decide which font you like for your thesis and just keep that.

If I remove the first line I get

[image]

If I remove the second line I get

[image]

By the way, I'd like better a punch in the eye than your chapter header. Just my opinion, of course.

Comment: I decided to keep Palatino and eulervm. What do you suggest for my chapter header?